# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: QTimer - why is Qtimer not available to my scripts?

Tags: qt, qtscript

I tried this snippet [suggested elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15348768/607407):

```
var timer = new QTimer();
timer.interval = 100; // set the time in milliseconds
timer.singleShot = true; // in-case if setTimout and false in-case of setInterval 
timer.timeout.connect(this, function(){console("in setTimout")});
timer.start();
```

Result:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: QTimer
```

Is there anything I need to set up for timers to work?

Comment: I don't think that the "snippet" that was suggested in the referenced post has ever worked. You need to look at the other answer that refers the context2d example, and specifically at its [Environment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24338852/1329652) class. QtScript doesn't just expose Qt classes to javascript like that.

Comment: See the answer I added to the original question.